# Using wildcards for column names in dynamic soql in apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I have a scenario where my columns names can be of type genesis__prod__c/docgen__prod__c/lnd__prod__c,etc depending upon which package is using my solution package. Here genesis,docgen and are different product packages using my solution.

My solution needs to fetch any of these(genesis__prod__c/docgen__prod__c/lnd__prod__c) fields from there respective sObjects in there products.

I want to construct a generic query which will omit the namespace using a wildcard and only look for prod__c in specified sObject. With this, I don't have to hardcode any namespace in my query.

for eg., I don't want to form my query like this

```
String query = 'select Id,Name,docgen__CL_Product__c from '+ sObjectType + ' where id= \'' + appId + '\'';
List<sObject> runtimeDeterminedObject = Database.query(query+' LIMIT 1');
```

Here I have specifically mentioned `docgen__CL_Product__c` name to be fetched from a runtime resolved sObject name `sObjectType` w.r.t an `appId`

How can I form a query where I do not have to provide namespace `docgen,genesis` before `prod__c`. I do not want to write `if-else` for each product which can utilize my package.

Comment: Seems, this is the only option with using if-else approach

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the namespace a variable that gets appended to the query based on some condition? Not exactly what you're looking for, but I'm assuming there's some way to determine the environment and then based on that you can adjust the query dynamically:

```
String env = someCondition ? 'genesis__' : 'docgen__';

String query = 'select Id, Name, ' + env + 'CL_Product__c from '+ sObjectType + ' where id= \'' + appId + '\'';
List<sObject> runtimeDeterminedObject = Database.query(query+' LIMIT 1');
```